# Lettuce BDD from Mac OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bdd, lettuce

I've been working through the Lettuce tutorial ([Lettuce Tutorial](http://lettuce.it/tutorial/simple.html)) to get BDD and Pyton to work together, all is in place.

The problem is I cannot run lettuce through my Mac OSX terminal, the tutorial shows lettuce specifying the test path and passing in lettuce as an argument;

user@machine:~/projects/mymath/tests$ lettuce

But this doesn't work for me as it returns path not found but I can cd to the same path where my tests reside.

When using Mac OSX terminal, what is the command to run lettuce and specify the tests path? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`lettuce` is the right command. 
it'll be easy for everyone else understands your issue if you can post the error message.

you may need to install your project in 'development mode' so that lettuce can find necessary modules.

check out this example bdd-python project: https://github.com/guoliang-dev/bdd-python it may helps.